# How to cast from class type object to double type in java

Tags: java, list, object, casting, subtraction

I have a method to subtract two values from two different list which are of class type.The code for subtraction is

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, List<Double>> diff()
  { 
      List<Double> z=new ArrayList<Double>();
     for(int i=0;i<st_jsp.size()&&i<ref_jsp.size();i++){
         Double x=(double) ref_jsp.get(i);
         Double y=st_jsp.get(i);

          if(x>y){
              z.add(x-y);
          }
          else{
          z.add(y-x);
          }

          dif.put("", z);
       }

    return dif;

  }
```

Here st_jsp and ref_jsp are two list such as `List<Ref_user_interface> st_jsp=new ArrayList<Ref_user_interface>();` and `List<Ref_user_interface> st_jsp=new ArrayList<Ref_user_interface>();` Ref_user_interface is my class name.
Thses two list holds value of in following way-

```
 ref.setSt1_vs1_bag6_rb(rs.getDouble(8));
 ref.setSt1_vs1_bag7_rb(rs.getDouble(9));
 ref.setSt1_vs1_bag8_rb(rs.getDouble(10));
 st_jsp.add(ref);
```

where ref is `Ref_user_interface ref=new Ref_user_interface();`
In my subtract method ,I'm getting an ** cannot convert from Ref_user_interface to Double** on line `Double x= ref_jsp.get(i);Double y=st_jsp.get(i);`.
Is there any way through which I can subtract my values from two list whcih hold data of object type.?

**EDIT-1**
I have getter and setter methods.But for each value of list,Do I have to include getter methods??For my getter and setter method please visit the link [setter method of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470911/displaying-list-in-proper-table-format-in-jsp-using-jstl)

**EDIT-2**

I have changed my subtraction method by all your answers as-

```
public LinkedHashMap<String, List<Double>> diff()
  {  

     List<Double> z=new ArrayList<Double>();

     for(int i=0;i<st_jsp.size()&&i<ref_jsp.size();i++)
     {
            Comaprision refObj = ref_jsp.get(i);
            Comaprision stObj = st_jsp.get(i);
            Double x =refObj.getBeam_current();
            x+=refObj.getBeam_energy();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag1_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag2_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag3_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag4_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag5_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag6_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag7_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag8_rb();
            x+=refObj.getSt2_vs2_bag9_rb();
             Double y = stObj.getBeam_current();
            y+=stObj.getBeam_energy();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag1_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag2_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag3_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag4_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag5_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag6_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag7_rb();
            y+=stObj.getSt2_vs2_bag8_rb();



          if((x>y)){

              z.add(x-y);
          }
          else{
          z.add(y-x);

          dif.put("", z);

       }
    return dif;

  }
```

but I can't understand that whether all the values at 1 index are being added and then comapred with y at index 1 and so on .Moreover this loop gives me 42 values.My **ref_jsp** has 21 rows and **st_jsp** has 78 rows but value of these rows are being repeated twice.I **can't understand this for loop**.Please help me to explain.I don't want to add up my values at a index,

My actual problem is to -->**I just want to compare value at getter of each index of x with value at getter of each index of y and find the difference.**

Comment: How to get all the getter methods whose setter is in list st_jsp in Double x and get all the getter methods whose setter is in list ref_jsp in Double y variable and then do comparision of both.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the thing is your list returns the object of `Ref_user_interface` so you can get value by calling the getter method like

```
ref_jsp.get(i).getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb()
```

and if you want all the getter methods the try this in your for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<st_jsp.size()&&i<ref_jsp.size();i++){
    Ref_user_interface refObj = ref_jsp.get(i);
    Ref_user_interface stObj = st_jsp.get(i);
    Double x = refObj.getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb();
    Double y = stObj.getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb();
    comparing(x,y);
    x =refObj.getSt1_vs1_bag7_rb();
    y = stObj.getSt1_vs1_bag7_rb();
    comparing(x,y)

     // and so on for all the getters method you have for this obj

     public void comparing(Double x,Double y){
           // write your comparing logic here and add value in map
          if(x > 0 && y > 0){
              if(x>y){
                 z.add(x-y);  
              }else{
                 z.add(y-x); 
              }  
          }else if(x>0){
             z.add(x);
          }else{
             z.add(y);
          }     
     }
```

and so on you get all the values you want and then use it according to your logic.

Comment: I have getter and setter methods,but I have 10 geeter methods .So for each get(i),I ahve to use ref_jsp.get(i).getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb() for 6 value,ref_jsp.get(i).getSt1_vs1_bag7_rb() for 7 value and so on??

Comment: that is up to you and your logic which value you want if you want the value of  `st1_vs1_bag6_rb` then you have to call `getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb()` which returns the value

Comment: My both the list hold all the values from receptive setter methods and I want to compare the value on one by one basis from both the list .Then how to supply values to double variable x and y???

Comment: I did.I'm asking that How my variable double x can hold all the values from the list ref_jsp and y holds all values from list st_jsp.In this case the variable are holding only single values.if they hold single values then ,how I will execute the if loop and put values in a map??

Comment: @MES do you want all the double values of `ref_jsp` in x variable and values of `st_jsp` in y variable and then compare the x and y or do you want the single single value of both for compairing

Comment: In both way it will be ok for me.I just want to compare values like value 1 of x with value 1 of y,then value 2 of x with value 2 of y and so on an dfind the difference between the two.

Comment: ok. your `ref_jsp` contains the object of  `Ref_user_interface` but which type of object your `st_jsp` holds.

Comment: st_jsp also contains object of Ref_user_interface

Comment: @amitbhardwaj are you adding all the values from **getter method** into the variables and then comparing them??

Comment: @SRY_JAVA yes because that's what i understand by op

Comment: @MES listen your list contains the object of same class so the getter methods return different value for different object now tell me what you really want to compare each getter method of 1 object to another or all the getter method of 1 object to another

Comment: @amitbhardwaj I want to compare each getter method of x variable with each getter method of Y variable.

Comment: @MES i updated my answer again as of now it compare 1 getter method of each object and put value in map. Is that what you want?

Comment: @amitbhardwaj Thanx a lot .Yup I want that only.I have one issue, If my x is empty and y has some value then also I want to print my y value.For this I have used if else if loop but,when I use it uit showing dead code for else if when I write else if(x==emp)
        {
         z.add(y);
        }          How to correct it.

Answer (score 2):

You need a getter like this setter `ref.setSt1_vs1_bag6_rb(rs.getDouble(8));`
. When you call `ref_jsp.get(i)` it returns `Ref_user_interface` then you need to call the new getter method to get what you want.

Update:

```
Double[] dbl_x = new Double[ref_jsp.size()];
Double[] dbl_y = new Double[ref_jsp.size()];
for(int i=0; i<ref_jsp.size(); i++){
   dbl_x[i] = ref_jsp.get(i).getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb();
}

for(int i=0; i<ref_jsp.size(); i++){
   dbl_y[i] = st_jsp.get(i).getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb();
}
```

At the end of this you have two arrays dbl_x and dbl_y and these arrays contain x and y values (which you referred earlier)

Then all you have to do is compare that two array and take decisions.

```
for(){
   if(dbl_x[i] > dbl_y[i]){
     // do this.
   }else{
     // do that.
   }
}
```

Above code snippet will give you a double array with the values you required. Do this for other set of values and the compare two arrays.

Note: `getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb()` is the getter method which returns the required values. Read [about getters here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/getter-setter-use-or-not-use)

Comment: can i make variable x as list and put all values from ref_jsp list into it??

Comment: No, It stores only the i th element
 eg: `Ref_user_interface x=ref_jsp.get(i);` here x has only one element which is at i th position

Comment: So,how can I put all ref_st list values into x varaible and comapre it with respective y varibales??

Comment: @MES Updated the answer with way to do what you want

Comment: ,I'm not able to understand that getSt1_vs1_bag6_rb(); will always gives one value ,then what is the use of looping.Similar to this getter method I have 9 other getter method with different values,so i have to execute this for loop for them also.I'm totally confused now.

Comment: @MES Updated more. Read about getters, see the Note at the end

Comment: Thanx. What will be there in second for loop??

Comment: @MES Please find it you self, what you want to do is compare values in two arrays now. I don't have your full code so I don't know what will come there.